# Multi Level Lookup in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: lookup-column

I would like to achieve multi level lookup as below

1. Cluster List structure
   [image]
2. Project List structure
   [image]
3. Project List Entries 
   [image]
4. Phase List structure
   [image]

When I select the cluster, it should show only the projects under the cluster but not all the projects?

Answer (score 2):

Aneenav answer uses a JavaScript library, which is a good one..

An alternative is InfoPath Forms, you can customize the Phase List Forms in InfoPath and apply additional rules with some data sources on the Project selection drop down..

You must have SharePoint Enterprise for that.

References:

[Customizing SharePoint List Forms in InfoPath 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180738%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[Cascading Drop-downs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharatgupta/archive/2013/03/07/create-cascading-dropdown-in-browser-enabled-infopath-form-using-infopath-2010.aspx)

Comment: Can you help with some samples.

Comment: check the references section in answer

Comment: Arsalan Adam Khatri, http://cascadefilterlookup.codeplex.com/documentation?referringTitle=Home what do you think?

Comment: Yes you can use this one as well, SPServices and SolidQ are of similar kind..

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to do filtered lookup, take a look at jQuery plugin called 'spservices' (http://spservices.codeplex.com/). It has got a function for filtering lookup columns. You'd have to customize the new and edit form and make use of above library.